# get all posts in custom post type by ACF field value

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, sql

I have a custom post type with custom fields(advanced custom fields plugin).
one of the custom fields named program_id.
i can`t understand how to get all of the posts in that CPT where the ACF field value is x, and only them.
i read ACF guide but i always get all of the post.

```
$student_query_args = [
  'post_type' => 'student_list',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 100,
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'meta_query' => [
      'key' => 'program_id',
      'value' => 5317,
  ],

];

$student_query = new WP_Query($student_query_args);

if ($student_query->have_posts()) {
  while ($student_query->have_posts()) {
      $student_query->the_post();
      echo '<br>' . the_title() . '<hr/>';
  }
}
```

Comment: try adding 'compare'  => 'LIKE', attribute in meta_query bellow value.

Comment: i did. and its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Meta Queries are nested arrays. See the [WP_Query section on meta queries](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters).

## Option 1

Use `meta_key` and `meta_value` directly in the query arguments, not as a meta query.

```
$student_query_args = [
  'post_type'       => 'student_list',
  'post_status'     => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'  => 100,
  'order'           => 'DESC',
  'meta_key'        => 'program_id',
  'meta_value'      => 5317,
];
```

## Option 2

The meta query approach. If you're adding multiple you would need multiple arrays. The default relation is `AND` but we'll supply it for clarity:

```
$student_query_args = [
  'post_type'       => 'student_list',
  'post_status'     => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'  => 100,
  'order'           => 'DESC',
  'meta_query'      => [
      'relation' => 'AND',
      [
          'key'     => 'program_id',
          'value'   => 5317,
      ],
  ],
];
```

Comment: you are right. i haven't nested the met_query

Comment: @DoronDavidowitz If the above solved your issue you can upvote and click the checkmark to show future readers that your issue has been addressed. Glad to help!

Comment: i did it all ready, but "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

as Howdy_McGee notice. 
the meta_query needs to be a nested array and to add 'LIKE' as comparison.
the correct answer is

```
$student_query_args = [
  'post_type' => 'student_list',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 100,
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'meta_query' => [
      'key' => 'program_id',
      'value' => 5317,
      'type' => 'numeric',
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
  ],

];

$student_query = new WP_Query($student_query_args);

if ($student_query->have_posts()) {
  while ($student_query->have_posts()) {
      $student_query->the_post();
      echo '<br>' . the_title() . '<hr/>';
  }
}
```